Java21: Illegal Rectangle is drawn while painting date time

Above image shows a rectangle which is in between time-value and am, In Java21.0.3, DateTime string has a character NNBSP which is converting to rectangle while painting it.
Following code illustrates the issue:
public class RunningStringPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private String text;

    public RunningStringPanel(String text, int delay) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setFont(new Font("MS Gothic", Font.ITALIC, 24));
        System.out.println(text);
        g.drawString(text, 10, 50); // Draw the string up to the current index
        System.out.println();
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Running String");
        RunningStringPanel panel = new RunningStringPanel(getText(), 200);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static final Long LONG_TIME = 1573430400000L;

    public static String getText() {

        Date created = new Date(LONG_TIME);
        DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL);
        String value = format.format(created);
        return value;
    }

}

What we tried to solve the issue

setting stdout.encoding and stderr.encoding to UTF-8
Use latest DateFormatter APIs also, that also results same
Change Windows Locale to UTF-8

Question: is there a way not to print rectangle in the string?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'd guess that you see Glyph 0: the .notdef glyph instead of U+202F,  Narrow No-Break Space. The font MS Gothic does not contain a glyph for U+202F…
